# TFHpple XML returning NULL

Tags: ios, xml, xpath

I'm having trouble with TFHpple and performing a basic XML search query. I've included the code and the XML response. I have a MutableArray that stores the data that is returned and then I NSLog it. This following code has worked just fine for me before when parsing an HTML page (of course I used initWIthHTMLData: instead). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     
 URLWithString:@"http://api.wmata.com/Rail.svc/Stations?     
 LineCode=RD&api_key=---------------------------"]];

// Create parser
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithXMLData:data]; //using XML data

//Pass in the search path
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser  searchWithXPathQuery:@"//Name"];


// Access the first cell
if([elements count] > 0) {

    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];

    // Get the text within the cell tag
    NSString *content = [element content];

    if (content) {
        //NSLog(@"%@", content);
        self.linkElements = [elements copy];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"No string found in the content");
    }


}else{
    NSLog(@"Nothing was found for your search query");
}


NSLog(@"The following is the result of the link elements array: %@", self.linkElements);
```

The following is an example xml response:

```
 <StationsResp xmlns="http://www.wmata.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Stations>
<Station>
  <Code>C02</Code>
  <Lat>38.9013327968</Lat>
  <LineCode1>BL</LineCode1>
  <LineCode2>OR</LineCode2>
  <LineCode3 i:nil="true" />
  <LineCode4 i:nil="true" />
  <Lon>-77.0336341721</Lon>
  <Name>McPherson Square</Name>
  <StationTogether1 />
  <StationTogether2 />
</Station>
<Station>
  <Code>C01</Code>
  <Lat>38.8983144732</Lat>
  <LineCode1>BL</LineCode1>
  <LineCode2>OR</LineCode2>
  <LineCode3 i:nil="true" />
  <LineCode4 i:nil="true" />
  <Lon>-77.0280779971</Lon>
  <Name>Metro Center</Name>
  <StationTogether1>A01</StationTogether1>
  <StationTogether2 />
</Station>
<Station>
  <Code>A01</Code>
  <Lat>38.8983144732</Lat>
  <LineCode1>RD</LineCode1>
  <LineCode2 i:nil="true" />
  <LineCode3 i:nil="true" />
  <LineCode4 i:nil="true" />
  <Lon>-77.0280779971</Lon>
  <Name>Metro Center</Name>
  <StationTogether1>C01</StationTogether1>
  <StationTogether2 />
</Station>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Station>
  <Code>C02</Code>
  <Lat>38.9013327968</Lat>
  <LineCode1>BL</LineCode1>
  <LineCode2>OR</LineCode2>
  <LineCode3 i:nil="true" />
  <LineCode4 i:nil="true" />
  <Lon>-77.0336341721</Lon>
  <Name>McPherson Square</Name>
  <StationTogether1 />
  <StationTogether2 />
</Station>
```

And changing from `[element content]` to `[element text]`, this is my output:

> McPherson Square

It looks like you could use `[element text]`. [Please refer to this similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920530/when-i-use-the-tfhpple-parser-html-on-iphone-and-already-find-the-node-but-th/13608230#13608230).

I hope it helps.