# When I use the TFHpple parser HTML on iPhone , and already find the node ,but the content return is NULL?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

the Code:

```
NSString *linkStr=@"http://www.voanews.com/content/obama_pledges_aid_to_drought_stricken_farmers/1484380.html";
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkStr]];

// Create parser  
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];  

//Get all the cells of the 2nd row of the 3rd table   
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//p[@class='article_date']"];  

// Access the first cell  
if ([elements count] > 0) 
{
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];  

    // Get the text within the cell tag  
    NSString *content = [element content];    
    NSLog(@"VOA = %@",content);       //Result : print NULL
}


[xpathParser release];  
[data release];
```

but I use the XPath Helper query the "//p[@class='article_date']" ,it's ok, but in my code the content is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code example, if I change `[element content]` for `[element text]`, my output is:

> VOA = August 11, 2012

[In its Github repo](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), they mention (at **USAGE** section):

> [e text]; // The text inside the HTML element (the content of the
>   first text node)

And looking at the source code of the **CONTENT** method it uses `objectForKey`, where `TFHppleContentKey = "nodeContent"`. See:

```c
static NSString * const TFHppleNodeContentKey = @"nodeContent"

// Returns this tag's innerHTML content.
- (NSString *) content
{
    return [node objectForKey:TFHppleNodeContentKey];
}
```

It seems that it's safe to use `[element text]` instead of `[element content]` in your example.

I hope it helps.